# Placeholder capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I've seen in many reference designs capacitors that were referred to as "placeholder" capacitors. what are these capacitors exactly needed for?

for example, in DDR4 SODIMM Design:
[image]

Comment: In this particular cases, it seems there is a footprint for a bulk device that is not actually placed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it is cheaper to draw a place for a capacitor and not mount it, so it can be populated later if necessary. It can be far more expensive to not draw a place for a capacitor and find out later that is is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to help tune the decoupling network if needed, but I believe Micron has the best in-depth answer here in their [TN-00-06 application note](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/tn0006.pdf?rev=35582931e2a945c0bbc4376b846b11c0)

If repetitive pulses are applied to the
power bus in this circuit, ringing can build in amplitude, resulting in a very noisy power
bus. To solve this problem, electrolytic capacitors, which have inherently high ESR, can
be placed across the bus to help dampen the ringing.
[image: Resonant circuit from app note]